# Insert Header in Django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I would like to insert a header in a Django form. I have the following fields:

```
Name
Price

Optional - Size
Optional - Color
```

But instead of having the "Optional - " in every optional item, I would like a header, so the form looks like this:

```
Name
Example

Optional fields:
Size
Color
```

(This is pseudocode but should be easy to illustrate my point)

I know i can render each individual form field in the HTML, but I would like to still use the {{ form.as_p }} (so I don't have to change the markup for every new field I want to add). Is there any way to define a Django property for the form so I can preserve the form.as_p and still have this additional header (and more headers for more sections of fields)?

Thank you

Comment: For another option, see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/24209246/362702

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for lack of a better option, I solved this problem by rendering the form's individual fields instead of the whole form.

Then I only have to do:

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    (...Field 1...)
</div>

<h1>My Own Header</h1>

<div class="fieldWrapper">
    (...Field 2...)
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I made it with JQuery.
It is very simple.

```
$('#id_size').parent().parent().before('<h1>optional</h1>');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Django hasn't such functionality but [django-uni-form](https://github.com/pydanny/django-uni-form) has :) This is an example from  [uni-form documentation](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-uni-form/en/latest/helpers.html#layouts) with small changes:

```
from uni_form.helper import FormHelper
from uni_form.layout import Layout, Fieldset

class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    [...]
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
                'name',
                'price'
            ),
            Fieldset(
                'Optional',
                'size',
                'color'
            ),
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='button white')
            )
        )
        return super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: With the current behavior of forms and form fields supplied with Django, it's virtually impossible to configure form objects to customize form rendering as you'd require it. django-uni-form, otoh, makes just that instantly possible.

Answer (score 0):

Quite an outdated post, but I spent several hours in finding a solution, so I would like to share it. Hope it's useful.

In your apps directory create a file named widgets.py, with following content, to extend the basic Widget class from Django:

```
# widgets.py 
from django.forms.widgets import Widget
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.template.loader import render_to_string


class HeaderWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, attrs=None, label=None, tag='h1'):
        self.label = label
        self.tag = tag
        super(HeaderWidget, self).__init__(attrs)

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        # change blocks/ according to your template path. In this case was templates/block
        widget = render_to_string("blocks/header-form-field.html", {
            'tag'   : self.tag,
            'label' : self.label,
            })
        return widget
```

Then create a file customfileds.py . Here we extend the Field Class with mostly nothing. The important thing is to avoid field validation, ase we have no input.

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.fields import Field
from . import widgets

class HeaderField(Field):
    widget = widgets.HeaderWidget
    # This is to avoid validation
    validators = []
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def clean(self, value=''):
        """
        It seem the clean method in mandatory when creating a Field class.
        Jaust return value without validation
        """
        return value
```

Then create the html template. Put it in a path that matches your
 widget = render_to_string("blocks/header-form-field.html"

```
#header-form-field.html
<{{ tag }} class="your-custom-class">{{ label }}</{{ tag }}>
```

Now you can add to your forms any HeaderField you need, like that:

```
class MyForm(GenericForm):

 header1   = customfileds.HeaderField(label=_(""),required=False,label_suffix='', 
                    widget=widgets.HeaderWidget(label=_("My custom Label text here"),tag="h3"))
 field 1   = whatever input field you have...
```

Here you can find same code in a gita page
https://gitlab.com/MaadiX/header-field-for-django-forms/blob/master/README.md